# XML validation: why is explicitly specifying a namespace not allowed in this case?

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, xml-namespaces

Given the following XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:foo="urn:foo" 
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
            targetNamespace="urn:foo" 
            version="3.0">
  <xsd:complexType name="Something">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="Nested" type="foo:NestedType"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="NestedType" />
</xsd:schema>
```

The following XML is valid:

```
<ns:Something xmlns:ns="urn:foo" 
              xsi:type="ns:Something" 
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Nested />
</ns:Something>
```

while this XML (only difference: 'Nested' is explicitly namespaced) isn't:

```
<ns:Something xmlns:ns="urn:foo" 
              xsi:type="ns:Something" 
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ns:Nested />
</ns:Something>
```

(at least according to the validator at http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/).

Why am I not allowed to specify the namespace on that `Nested` element? Wouldn't I only be more explicit than strictly necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because it in the XSD you have defined, the  `elementFormDefault` is implicitely set to `"unqualified"`.

Thus you can't set a namespace prefix to your elements.

Comment: Ah, of course. I've been working with XSD's with only elementFormDefault="qualified" for so long (WS-Addressing, WS-BaseNotification, WS-... and a dozen XSD's our customers derived from those) that I forgot there was even another possibility